# Cálculo em JavaScript

Tags: jquery

Tenho dois campos de input onde digito valores.
Coloquei máscara para que quando digitar o valor ficar no formato 0,00.
Como faço um simples cálculo com valores 0,00? Pois tenho uma fórmula que me passaram e que o resultado, ou da 0 ou aparece NaN.
Segue o código da fórmula, do cálculo.

```
$(function(){
    $("#precoVendaNoMercado, #descPromo , #descFinan ").change (function(){
        if($("#precoVendaNoMercado").val() != "" && $("#descPromo").val() != "" && $("#descFinan").val() != "") {
            precoDeVendaRealizado = parseFloat($("#precoVendaNoMercado").val() * (1- (parseFloat($("#precoVendaNoMercado").val())) + parseFloat($("#precoVendaNoMercado").val())) / 100 );
            console.log('Calculo:'+precoDeVendaRealizado);
        }
    });
});
```

Fiz o que vc sugeriu @Diego Souza. E no console do chrome aponta pra linha:

```
var desFinan = descFinan.replace('.', '').replace(',', '.'); precoDeVendaRealizado = precoVeNoMerc * (1 - (desPromo + desFinan) / 100 );
```

Dizendo "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined"

Comment: estás sempre a fazer a conta com o `$("#precoVendaNoMercado").val()`, é o correto? Não deveria ser: `precoDeVendaRealizado = parseFloat($("#precoVendaNoMercado").val() * (1- (parseFloat($("#descPromo").val())) + parseFloat($("#descFinan").val())) / 100 );`

Comment: Podes dar exemplos de valores que tens? A máscara também adiciona pontos?

Comment: @Sergio, estou transformando meus dados em float, com o parseFloat, mas quando somos valores com centavos, o resultado não aparece com esse centavos, exemplo:
1,11 + 1,11 o resultado fica apenas 2 e não 2,22.
Depois de converter os dados em float, eu faço o seguinte:
variavel1 + variavel2, está errado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você deve substituir as "," por "." ou deve converter os valores para float:

```
var valorConvertido = parseFloat($("#precoVendaNoMercado").val());
```

Comment: Valeu @ Kayo Bruno.
E como faço, depois, para exibir o resultado no formato 0,00?

Comment: Da um replace substituindo ''." por ",".

Comment: estou transformando meus dados em float, com o parseFloat, mas quando somos valores com centavos, o resultado não aparece com esse centavos, exemplo:
1,11 + 1,11 o resultado fica apenas 2 e não 2,22.
Depois de converter os dados em float, eu faço o seguinte:
variavel1 + variavel2, está errado?

Answer (score 2):

Remova todos os pontos e virgulas da *string* transformando-a em inteiro, depois divida por cem, trazendo as casas decimais em forma numérica.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $("#go").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        if(
          $("#precoVendaNoMercado").val() != "" && 
          $("#descPromo").val() != "" && 
          $("#descFinan").val() != ""
        ) {
          // Trabalhe com uma variável, é sempre melhor
          var valor = $("#precoVendaNoMercado").val();
            
          if (valor.indexOf(",") == -1) { // verifica se tem casas decimais
             valor += ",00"; // Se não tiver coloca
             var dec = 2; // Duas casas decimais
             var ndec = 100; // 100 para duas casas decimais (10 para 1, 1000 para 3)
              
            } else {
                // Calcula para quanto tem que dividir para voltar as casas decimais
                var dec = valor.substring(valor.indexOf(",")+1).length; // Casas decimais
                var ndec =  Math.pow(10, dec); // Valor para calcular (10 elevado ao número de casas decimais)
            }

          // Remove pontos, vírgulas e espaços em branco
          valor = valor.replace(/\,\./, "").trim();
          
          // Transforma para numérico inteiro e depois divide para o quantidade de casas decimais
          valor = parseInt(valor) / ndec;
            
          // Calcula a formula
          var precoDeVendaRealizado = valor * (1 - valor + valor) / 100 ;
          // Transforma em string voltando o divisor decimal para vírgula
          var visivel = precoDeVendaRealizado.toString().replace('.',',');

$("#result").text('Calculo: '+visivel);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="precoVendaNoMercado" value="54,21"> <button id="go">GO</button>
<p id="result"></p>
```

<sub>Não intendi muito bem o objetivo da fórmula, mas da forma que ela está poderia ser resumida para `valor / 100`.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Você deve criar uma função ou fazer na mesma uma rotina que tire as vírgulas. Vírgula é considerado texto (string) e não se faz cálculos com textos.

Mas o certo é substituir a vírgula por ponto. E tirar os pontos dos milhares.

**replace** pode te ajudar.

```
var valor = '190.000,00';
var valorFormatado = valor.replace('.', '').replace(',', '.');
```

Daí sim você pode fazer o cálculo, visto que o ponto não é considerado como texto se não estiver entre aspas.

Comment: como fica valores do tipo 1.000.000.000,00, usando esse replace('.', '').replace(',', '.')?

Outra coisa, como se comenta ou responde, com formatação de código?